# How do I modify my web.config file to support SQL Server 2016?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection

I'm totally new to C#/.Net development. I've read extensive documentation about the [web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa306178.aspx) file on msdn and still am unsure what to change.

If answered would you please provide an example of what I should do? I can provide more info if necessary.

Comment: You are not supposed to, `connectionstring` properties stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to provide information about SQL Server, You just need to give correct connection string, which points to your database.

Something like:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="myConnectionString" 
         connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pushing my modifications through source control now. Should everything succeed, I will come back and mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is one way if you are just using some local database.

Otherwise you can set it up like this:

```
<connectionStrings >
<add
     name="myConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And then in your code you should write:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

And then at last you can set up your connection variable something like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Are you using the entity framework? Because then it can be generated automatically.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using EF. From what I've read I need to use a Master Data Services and then reference that in my web.config file. I'm still looking into how to implement that. Confused as hell. Appreciate your answer though!